# PHP autoload function does not work sometimes

Tags: php, autoload

I have strange problem with autoload function. I have this code:

```
function __autoload($class) {
    echo "in autoload function: ".$class."<br/>";
    require_once $class.".php";
}
TestClass::testMethod();
echo is_file("Debug.php") ? " file exist " : "file not exist";
echo "<br/>";
echo  class_exists('Debug') ? "class exist" : "class not exist";
Debug::getIncludeExecutionTime($include, $time);
```

And output is:

```
in autoload function: TestClass
file exist
class not exist
Fatal error: Class 'Debug' not found in Z:[my local host path] on line 207
```

So, there is misseed 'in autoload function Debug'. Most strangest there - if I invoke Debug class in other function, or in other place, autoload work.

Why autoload function was not invoked? What can be reasons? There is no spl_autoload_register functions on project.

Comment: There is no namespaces

Comment: I found solution, that was Smarty template engine.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things. First if you work with namespaces you have to include the correct namespace. You can make a `var_dump` on your `$class` variable to look if the classname is correct.

The other thing is that you should verify that your path is really correct. Perhaps you should specify the complete path to your file with `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)`.

```
function __autoload($class) {
    echo "in autoload function: ".$class."<br/>";
    if(is_file(__DIR__.'/'.$class.".php")) {
        require_once __DIR__.'/'.$class.".php";
    }
}
```

And perhaps you should check on that point if the file exists.

Comment: there is no namepaces, and file is exist, because is_file("Debug.php") return true. There is weird behavior - at first script must invoke autoload, and if it does not found class, throw an error. But in my case script throws error without autoload function.

Comment: Hmm... have you defined a class in your debug file? Sounds a bit stupid :D but sometimes the solution is very simple.

Comment: I found what exactly goes wrong - Smarty autoload kill my autoload.

Comment: Hmm ok ... thats a problem if you have another function.